# How do I tell if a std::variant holds any value at all?

Tags: c++, c++17, std-variant

I already know how to use `std::variant` fairly well with `std::get_if()`, `std::get()` and `std::visit()`.  But, what if I just want a simple way to tell if a variant has ever been initialized to any value?  That is, I don't care what the value is, I just want a boolean test.  How do I do that?

For example, suppose I declare a variant on the stack:

```
std::variant<int, double> data;
```

Then, my function goes on and might or might not initialize this variable.  At the end of my function, I want to test if it was initialized.

- I looked at the `index()` function.  That returns 0 both for an uninitialized variant *and* for one I initialize to the first type declared.
- I looked at the `valueless_by_exception()` function but that returns false whether I initialize the variant or not.

About the only thing I could think of to compare it to a default constructed one, like this:

```
using Data = std::variant<int, double>;

Data data;

// ... code here that might initialize data or might not...

if (data == Data())
    // Not initialized
else
    // Initialized
```

This seems to work, but reading [the comments on `operator==()` for `std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/operator_cmp), it seems like this behavior is undefined.

So, is this a safe way to test, or is there another way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
std::variant<int, double> data;
```

`data` is initialized. A `std::variant` is always initialized with one of its values, unless it's `valueless_by_exception()`.

Unless a `std::variant` instance has an explicit constructor, the first variant alternative gets default-constructed. This specific `data` holds an `int` value, that's default-constructed.

If the first `std::variant` value does not have a default constructor than the variant cannot be default-constructed, and must have an explicit constructor.

When it is desired to have a concept of a variant that doesn't "really" (with the word "really" in air-quotes) have a default value: the usual convention is to have [`std::monostate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/monostate) as the first variant value. This is what `std::monostate` is for.

```
std::variant<std::monostate, int, double> data;
```

This variant is default-constructed and holds a `std::monostate` value. Its `index()` is 0. You can consider this variant to be uninitialized, whatever that actually means to your application, when your variant has a 0 index.

There's nothing special about `std::monostate` itself. It's just an empty class. If you visit a variant with a `std::monostate` value your visitor needs to deal with a `std::monostate` alternative.

Answer (score 6):

As with anything that needs a separate "no value" state, you can use `std::optional`:

```
std::optional<std::variant<int, double>> data{}; // doesn't have a value
// ...
if (data.has_value()) {
   // ...
}
```